# mysql result returns ?(question mark) instead of Ö etc

Tags: php, mysql

When i return a row from my mySQL database, I get a ? instead of some characters eg:ò, à
 etc. My mysql row and table are set to utf8_unicode_ci, so I think the database is storing it correctly but php isnt returning it correctly.

Think it has something to do with  `mysql_set_charset` but cant get it to work properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
  <?php 
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(queryDb("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE uuid='".$_COOKIE['uuid']."'")))
 {
  $first_name = $row['first_name'];
  $last_name = $row['last_name'];
  $gender = $row['gender'];


  $ileach_first_name = $row['ileach_first'];
  $ileach_last_name = $row['ileach_last'];

}

 //If Ileach Name is blank

  if($ileach_last_name == "" || $ileach_first_name == ""){


  // Get ileach last name
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(queryDb("SELECT * FROM ileach_last_names WHERE eng_name='$last_name'"));

  $ileach_last_name = $row['gae_name']; 


  if($ileach_last_name == "") {
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(queryDb("SELECT * FROM ileach_last_names order by rand() limit 1"));
    $ileach_last_name = $row['gae_name'];}  



  //Get ileach First Name
   //If Male
    if($gender == 'M') {

     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(queryDb("SELECT * FROM ileach_first_names_m WHERE eng_name='$first_name'"));

     $ileach_first_name = $row['gae_name']; 

     //If no name is selected, get one randomly 
      if($ileach_first_name == "") {
       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(queryDb("SELECT * FROM ileach_first_names_m order by rand() limit 1"));
     $ileach_first_name = $row['gae_name']; }
    }
   //If Female 


    else{

     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(queryDb("SELECT * FROM ileach_first_names_f WHERE eng_name='$first_name'"));

     $ileach_first_name = $row['gae_name']; 

     //If no name is selected, get one randomly 
     if($ileach_first_name == "") {
       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(queryDb("SELECT * FROM ileach_first_names_f order by rand() limit 1"));
     $ileach_first_name = $row['gae_name'];}
    }




  //Save ileach name into db

   mysql_query("UPDATE customer SET ileach_first = '$ileach_first_name'
   WHERE uuid='".$_COOKIE['uuid']."' ");

   mysql_query("UPDATE customer SET ileach_last = '$ileach_last_name'
   WHERE uuid='".$_COOKIE['uuid']."' ");
  }


  //Stitch name together.

  $full_ileach_name .=$ileach_first_name;
  $full_ileach_name .= " ";
  $full_ileach_name .= $ileach_last_name;





?>
```

Comment: `but cant get it to work properly.` - what did you try?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Think it has something to do with mysql_set_charset" - yes, very likely.

```
$mysql = mysql_connect(...); // TODO: error handling
mysql_select_db('...', $mysql);  // TODO: error handling
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $mysql);  // TODO: error handling
```

For mor detailed information we need to know more about the function queryDB() and related stuff (like e.g. where the database connection is established)

see also:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/charset-connection.html
- http://docs.php.net/mysql_set_charset

Comment: The connection was stored in another file, slotted in mysql_set_charset and it worked like a dream! Cheers!

Comment: was running this locally on php 5.2.6, and it worked fine, but once id deployed it to my server running on 5.1.6 it didnt work. 

However, I stumbled uppon this line: 
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

which worked a treat!

Comment: With **mysqli** you can use: 
`$mysqliConnectionObj->set_charset('utf8');`

Answer (score 5):

try to put this after mysql_select_db:

```
mysql_query ( "set character_set_client='utf8'" );
mysql_query ( "set character_set_results='utf8'" );
mysql_query ( "set collation_connection='utf8_unicode_ci'" );
```

Comment: This let's e.g. mysql_real_escape() in the dark about the changed charset. see http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html which was apparently written before mysql_set_charset was introduced in php 5.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Send as a first query this:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

Should work ;)

- MySQL stores text correctly, and PHP is correctly formatting, but problem is laying in connection charset :)
- Like @VolkerK suggested, it may be a better idea to use [mysql_set_charset](http://docs.php.net/mysql_set_charset) func

Comment: This let's e.g. mysql_real_escape() in the dark about the changed charset. http://docs.php.net/mysql_set_charset says: "Using mysql_query() to execute SET NAMES ..  is not recommended."

Comment: I'm using PDO and this is working great :)
So i wrote that this "Should work" when using mysql/mysqli driver

Comment: But you're probably also using parametrized queries with PDO, don't you?

Comment: Yep :) i'm not standing after that "like a stone", just it works for me, (for polish set of additional chars), but i may be wrong :)
PS and it passes escaping in pena-tests, so i'm using this query to set conn charset :)

Comment: If you use parametrized queries/server-side prepared statements there's nothing wrong with SET NAMES (as far as I know). But if you rely on escaping with e.g. mysql_real_escape_string() like you have to with the old php-mysql module it opens a rare but unnecessary hole. Unnecessary because there is a function (mysql_set_charset) that specifically deals with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the encoding of the file itself correct?

Have you tried using utf8_encode or utf8_decode?
see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

If utf8_encode works, I would assume that the results from the database are in the wrong charset.

If utf8_decode works, I would assume that the file has the wrong charset or maybe the browser is parsing it in the wrong charset.
This can be fixed with a header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

or in <head>:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

see: http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html