# Cannot display unicode data in php

Tags: php, mysqli, unicode, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmysql for my website. And I store Unicode in `utf8_general_ci`.

When I tried to display the Unicode column using php some `?????????` is displayed instead of Unicode data.

Note: I just tried to retrieve the data from database using mysqli.

**Thanks**

Comment: Thanks but not working. Should I change `utf8_general_ci` to `utf8mb4_general_ci`

Comment: Hi Krity, try using `utf8mb4_general_ci` or `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` . I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hello No sir, both of them are not working

Comment: where is your code for the encoding in front end and php?

Comment: Yes I am using php

Comment: you should use same encoding for database, php and your front end then you won't have this problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547278/mysql-result-returns-question-mark-instead-of-%C3%96-etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275411/php-output-showing-little-black-diamonds-with-a-question-mark

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439324/arabic-language-in-php-mysql-appears-question-marks-in-html

Comment: I don't understand. I use both  `utf8mb4_general_ci` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` in database as Collation. Now what should i do in PHP?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/characters-appear-as-question-marks-using-mysql-204051027.html

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave Thnks It works. I wish I could accept your answer and up-vote

Comment: Glad it worked. Hope I helped you even if I was unable to answer it instead of comment. Highly appreciated.

Comment: @KrityShrestha Additionally, you can copy and paste the link through which you found the solution. By doing so, it will help other people as well if they stuck to the same situation. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave welcum. And I hope it will help other too

Comment: See "Question marks" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: @KrityShrestha Yes indeed.